# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE with selenium using proxy (chrome webdriver)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, proxy

I've been trying to scrape some websites and decided to use proxies for a while it went fine i guess but now I'm getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE quite often and once every 10 or so tries, the page will load correctly, without changing the code, of course.
When I'm not running headless and I get an empty response, I can click the "reload" button on the chrome webdriver and the page will sometimes load.

It's got something to do with the fact that I use a proxy but I can't really work out why it's working sometimes and why it gives me an empty response so often.

Has anyone else run into a similar problem?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

PROXY = "35.230.111.164" + ":" + "8888"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME["proxy"] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "noProxy": None,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "autodetect": False,
}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(
    "https://whatismyipaddress.com/"
)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="footer_tc_privacy_button_2"]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced problems with proxy + chrome/chromedriver forever now, and the only solution I came up with was trying to detect the error and reload programmatically, something like this:

```py
err = driver.find_element_by_css('#main-frame-error .error-code')

# found chrome err! lets reload...
if(err){
   driver.get(driver.current_url)
}
```